# Is "to become" used as "to make" synonym in the sentence?

Tags: word-usage

The sentence is

> Enabling change throughout our business to become people and 
>   planet positive.

from [IKEA sustainability report](http://www.ikea.com/ms/en_US/img/ad_content/2015_IKEA_sustainability_report.pdf)

Comment: I think the meaning is "..to become positive about people and the planet".

Comment: **people-positive** and **planet-positive** are newfangled jargon. The construction is analogous to "planet-friendly". In IKEA's case, planet-positive would mean conscious of the effects upon the environment of the manufacturing and sale of household goods and furniture. People-positive would mean something like "offering affordable merchandise which meets the needs of people, and free lunch when you spend above a certain amount".

Comment: @TRomano _People_ and _planet_ are just good ol' fashion _noun adjuncts_ here, aren't they?

Comment: @P. E. Dant: A grammatical description is not the be-all and end-all of answers.  But to say that the jargon is newfangled doesn't imply that the underlying grammatical construction is new, in any case.

Comment: @TRomano I didn't know the usage is fsngled at all; I assumed that some Ikea copywriter came up with it. I guess I need to shop more. :)

Comment: @P.E. Dant: https://www.google.com/search?q=planet+positive&oq=planet+positive&aqs=chrome..69i57.3561j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

No; "people and planet positive" is an adjective phrase, and *become* is being used in its usual sense. Grammatically, "people and planet positive" is the adjective *positive* with the complements *people* and *planet*. (It might have been better to punctuate it as "people– and planet-positive".) Semantically, the relevant sense of *positive* is extended from the term *[sex-positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex-positive_movement)*, and means roughly "supporting" or "promoting". In your example, I think it comes off as insincere corporate buzzword jargon, though others may disagree.

For some additional context, IKEA's "People & Planet Positive" strategy is explained as follows on page 8 of the sustainability report that you linked to:

> Our vision is to create a better life for the many people. [sic] Our People & Planet Positive strategy is one of the ways we work towards this. It sets out how we are going all-in on the things that really matter, from going 100% for renewable energy to sourcing all of our cotton and wood from sustainable sources. We have made good progress, but we are determined to do even more.
>
> Our strategy focuses on three areas:
>
> 1. […]